# .txt vs .csv file format for data table manipulation

Tags: python

I'm working on a program that needs to read values from excel table and then do some operations on them and save the results as a new file.

As python can't read an excel file directly, i first have to convert the file to .txt or .csv. It got me thinking if there's any real difference between the two file formates. The first one just seperates the two columns with \t and the other with a semicolon (when using .read() function in python). In case there isn't, why should one prefer .txt over another and vice versa?

Comment: `.txt` is not a format, but may conventionally mean "csv with tab separators" in some contexts.

Comment: you can add any extension you want to any file ...  also with xlrd you can read xls files no problem

Comment: No difference. A file saved as .txt could also have comma separated values in it rather than tab separated.

Comment: Excel generated CSV files are the work of Satan. Do not use them as they vary wildly per Office version, user settings and locale. Try to find a decent Excel reader/writer for Python, this one perhaps: http://www.python-excel.org/ ?

Comment: can't i just convert excel to .txt file and then read the information instead of converting it to xlrd with python-excel? The tables i need to process are fairly simple, just some information as strings on each column (up to 5) and then one coulmn empty and then a number value :d

Answer (score 2):

As was pointed out by TokenMacGuy, TXT is not a file format, and it could mean multiple things in different contexts.
Generally you export tables in either CSV (comma separated values) or TSV (tab separated values).
Which you should choose depends mainly on your data: if your data has commas in it but not tabs, you should go for TSV. Most programs should quote your cells (insert a quote in the beggining and end of each cell).

Finally, as to how to actually read these files in python, you could either do it by hand and risk office upgrades, or use [the proper module in the stdlib, which has excellent documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html)